# Execute SQL stored procedure from QueriesTableAdapter in DataSet at view design

Tags: sql-server, winforms, dataset

I have added a query to the DataSet, in view design, because I want to execute a stored procedure, how can I reference it in code and pass the parameters?

Comment: Procedural code (like stored procedures) is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag for the actual, concrete database **system** you're using - whether it be `mysql`, `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2` or something else entirely....

Comment: Sorry, with SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you added a stored proc to the tableadapter through the designer, the dataset generates a method for the tableadapter when saved, including any parameters required for the stored procedure.
e.g.

```
Dim ta As New ArticleDataSetTableAdapters.ArticleTableAdapter
ta.Connection = myConnection
ta.ArticleSendDeliveryMail(body, art_id, sender)
```